# How do I remove the tab bar off a certain page in the stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

How do I remove the tab bar from only the "NewChatScreen" while keeping it on the "Group Chats" screen?

```
<GroupchatStack.Navigator>
    <GroupchatStack.Screen
        name="Group Chats"
        component={GroupchatMainPageScreen}
        options={{tabBarStyle:{display:'flex'}}}  //DOES NOT WORK
    />

    <GroupchatStack.Screen
        name="NewChatScreen"
        component={CreateNewChat}
        options={{tabBarStyle:{display:'none'}}}   //DOES NOT WORK
    />
</GroupchatStack.Navigator>

<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeTab"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
     />
     <Tab.Screen
        name="GroupChatTab"
        component={GroupchatStackScreen}
     />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Create a parent StackNavigator with child stack Tab.Navigator and "Group Chats" as stack.

Comment: The GroupchatsStackScreen is already a stack. How do I remove the tab bar off certain screens of the stack?

Comment: `<Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="" component="" /> // add here your screen
<TabNavigator>
<Stack.Screen name="" component={[ANOTHER_STACK_NAVIGATOR]} />
</TabNavigator>
</Stack.Navigator>`

Basically, If you dont want to show tab bar on specific page then you don't need to add that screen in GroupchatStack navigator. (Recommended way)

Solution 2 : create custom bottom tab. Based on navigation state, you can hide.